# How to implement max(A) where A is a double complex matrix using Eigen library

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

I am having a matrix A of data type double. I am able to find max(A) with Eigen library .How to modify my code when I choose a matrix of data type double complex by taking absolute values as comparing parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <complex.h>
using namespace Eigen;


int main()

{

    MatrixXcd A(2, 2), B(1,2);
A<<-4,-12,
    6,8;
B=A.colwise().maxCoeff();
cout<<"The solution is A:\n"<<B<<endl;
retun 0
}
```

As an example

> > a = [4 + 2*i, -12-3*i;6-1*i,8+1*i]

```
a =

   4.0000 + 2.0000i -12.0000 - 3.0000i
   6.0000 - 1.0000i   8.0000 + 1.0000i
```

I need to get

> > max(a)

```
ans =

   6.0000 - 1.0000i -12.0000 - 3.0000i
```

Comment: Which number is larger? `1+2i` or `2+i`?

Comment: You can't compare two complex numbers, you can only compare their modulus. What will be the equalent command for abs(x1)>abs(x2) in Eigen.

Comment: So, you already know it. Read your own question. Does it mention anything about modulus? Why don't you state clearly what you want in the question? Edit your question and state it clearly, or it would be dismissed as illogical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [redux](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a63ce1e4fab36bff43bbadcdd06a67724):

```
B = A.colwise().redux(
    [](const auto& a,const auto&  b) {
        if(std::abs(a) < std::abs(b))
            return b;
        return a;
    }
);
```

Comment: On printing B it will give me the absolute value. I need to print  the element of the matrix A having the maximum absolute value

Comment: What change should be made so that after comparison of absolute values, I get back the corresponding real and imaginary value??